# why do some patterns have classes with seperate data classes in oo design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, class

I have just been reading over some of my old oo design books and something that I dont quite follow.

If im using something like the repository pattern lets say.

i.e:

```
    interface ICarRepository {

      IEnumerable<car> GetCarCollection();

    }

    class MsSqlCarRepository : ICarRepository {

      IEnumerable<car> GetCarcollection(){ ................ };

    }

    class car {

      int CarId;
      string CarName;

    }
```

The above code is roughly c# but isnt really relevant.

Although the above works well and is what I generally see and use myself, All the books I read about oo generally state that an object combines its Methods and Properties togeather.

So Ignoring the interface part shouldnt it be more along the lines of:

```
    class car {

      int CarId;
      string CarName;

      IEnumerable<car> GetCarcollection(){ ................ };

    }
```

????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is so that you can substitute for a different repository eg PostgresSQLCarRepository without needing to change your Car class.

You could use this where you seperate out your repository classes into a seperate library and then load them by Dependency Injection.

So if you compiled multiple libary dlls, one that talks postgres, one that talks mssql, one that talks XML you could use any of them with your code without worrying about recompiling your car classes.

--EDIT After Comment

After the additional comments the question appears to be more why does this real wolrd design pattern appear to not follow the basic principles of OO?

The short answer is it does follow the basic principles of OO.

The long answer...

The basic idea of the OO (And this is overly simplistic without going into massive amounts of inheritance, polymorphism etc) is that you group together a collection of properties about a specific entity and methods that operate on a specific entity into a single class.

The GetCarCollection() method does not apply to a single car instance.  It applies to the Repository, because you are asking the repository to return a collection of cars.  However a method like Start() may be method against a car because it would apply specifically to that one car instance.

On top of that you additionally have properties that could be readonly and you usually hide the backing fields to be only accessible to class instance itself so instead you might have

```
public class car { 

  private int _carId; 
  private string _carName; 
  private int speed=0;

  public Car(int carId) {
    this._carId=carId;
  }

  public int CarId {
    get { return this._carId; } 
  }

  public string  CarName {
    get { return this._carName; }
    set { this._carName=value; }
  }

  public int Speed {
    get { return this._speed; }
  }

  public void Accelerate() {
    if (this._speed<91) this._speed++;
  }
} 

public class MsSqlCarRepository : ICarRepository {    

  public MsSqlCarRepository(SqlConnection conn) {.....}

  IEnumerable<car> GetCarcollection(){ ................ }

}    

public class XmlCarRepository : ICarRepository {    

  public XmlCarRepository(string FileName) {.....}

  IEnumerable<car> GetCarcollection(){ ................ }

}
```

The example you gave may have not seemed very OO to you, but it was more because it was simplistic.  As the level of detailed and complexity to your objects increases you should see how this is in fact an OO approach and starts to diverge from you C struct and manager approach.

Comment: I understand what the repository pattern is used for that is not really my question

Comment: So what is your question? If you understand the repository pattern then merging the methods doesn't make sense as you make the pattern impossible?

Comment: My fundamental question is really why do real world examples (the repository just being one I picked from a hat) never seem to follow what is written in the learn oo books etc. though Paul Grime below does explain this instance of the repository example quite well. But as I have said above the repository pattern isnt really doing things any differently than using a struct and some struct manager code and as put forward above C is certainly not oo. Or maybe im missing something here. Its not so much a question about the repository pattern as such.

Comment: No I can see were you coming from here and that does make sense.

Comment: I suppose Im mixing up methods being really verbs to the object as opposed to actions that act upon the object (Like getting a collection of cars from ....).

Answer (score 3):

It's all about coupling between the layers of different parts of your code. Separating your domain models from the operations/contracts that could be performed on those domain models allows you to reuse those domain models more easily in other contexts. Imagine for example that someone wants to define some other operations with this Car model than `GetCarcollection`. In this case he would write a different repository interface and you won't need to modify this domain model. On the other hand if you defined the `GetCarcollection` method inside the Car object this other consumer of the model won't be happy as he might not care about your method but would like to use his own.

Comment: I know why its done and it works well, what I dont understand is why every book I own on oo programming doesnt follow this method and teaches something different in being that an object is self contained. So in effect the first car class above doesnt actually contain any methods.

Comment: @William Humphreys, the example you provided is the repository design pattern. In this pattern you have separate contract for fetching your domain models, otherwise you would need an instance of the domain model in order to fetch other domain models which wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Its rather like we are using an old C struct to hold the data and some type of stuct manager which to mee doesnt seen to be oo at all and is no different to what I was doing in plain old C 30 years ago

Comment: @William Humphreys, C is not an object oriented language.

Comment: I know its not thats my whole point if this is oo why is it no different

Comment: @William Humphreys, because that's how the creators of the repository design pattern decided to define it. There is nothing preventing you from putting your entire application into a single humongous class. That way everything will be self contained. But that's not the point. An maintainable application is achieved by separating and abstracting the different layers as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A 'car collection' isn't an intrinsic property of a car. A garage or a car-park might have a car collection.

Comment: I agree perhaps a GetColor() Method would be a better example

Comment: But to be honest your answer makes more sense in thinking about the repository class as synonymous with the car park or garage...

Comment: So In effect if I was using a different car park I would write a different car park class (repository)

Answer (score 0):

The car is not a car-repository. Otherwise you'd need to have a car to get a car.

GetCarCollection *could* be a static method, but that then wouldn't allow you to mock or inject the repository, and doesn't represent separation of concerns (i.e. Is the role of the type to *represent* a car? Or is it to *fetch* cars?).

Where to draw the line here is subjective, and may vary on project requirements.